# How to apply a custom button style to a toolbar menu?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The custom button style below encapsulates some primitive button styles, so we can style any button according to a condition in our views.

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    enum Style {
        case bordered
        case borderedProminent
    }
    
    var style: Style
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch style {
        case .bordered:
            BorderedButtonStyle().makeBody(configuration: configuration)
        case .borderedProminent:
            BorderedProminentButtonStyle().makeBody(configuration: configuration)
        }
    }
}
```

It works when used on a classic `Button`. But when applied to a `Menu` stylized as a `.button` it doesn't. Why?

[Video of what's happening](https://imgur.com/a/v5fszTR)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var condition: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button("Toggle style", action: { $condition.animation().wrappedValue.toggle() })
                }
                Section {
                    Button("Stylized button", action: {})
                        .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(style: condition ? .borderedProminent : .bordered)) // this one works…
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Toolbar Menu Demo")
            .toolbar {
                Menu("Filter", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease") {
                    // …
                }
                .menuStyle(.button)
                .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(style: condition ? .borderedProminent : .bordered)) // …but that one doesn't :(
                .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What confuses me is that if button styles `.bordered` or `.borderedProminent` are used independently on the `Menu` (i.e. by applying `.buttonStyle(.bordered)` or `.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)`), then the `Menu` button is perfectly stylized.

Tested in Xcode 15 beta 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Suprafen answer, and with a few adjustments, the solution is to create a custom `MenuStyle` that wraps the button styles. Also, keeping the `systemImage` property on the `Menu` is quite feasible.

```
struct CustomMenuStyle: MenuStyle {
    enum ButtonStyle {
        case bordered
        case borderedProminent
    }
    
    var buttonStyle: ButtonStyle
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch buttonStyle {
        case .bordered:
            Menu(configuration)
                .menuStyle(.button)
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
        case .borderedProminent:
            Menu(configuration)
                .menuStyle(.button)
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var condition: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button("Toggle style", action: { condition.toggle() })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Toolbar Menu Demo")
            .toolbar {
                Menu("Filter", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease") {
                    // …
                }
                .menuStyle(CustomMenuStyle(buttonStyle: condition ? .borderedProminent : .bordered))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, but instead of conforming to `ButtonStyle`, you would need to conform to `MenuStyle` to create your own custom style for menu. Though, keep in mind, that it won't work with systemImage like in your case. The way you can provide system image, is by passing needed parameter to the style's initializer.

```
struct CustomMenuToolbarStyle: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Other content")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Menu("Filter") {
                    Button("Action 1") {}
                    Button("Action 2") {}
                    Button("Action 3") {}
                }
                .menuStyle(CustomMenuStyle(systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomMenuStyle: MenuStyle {
    let systemImage: String
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Menu(configuration)
            Image(systemName: systemImage)
        }
        .padding(8)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(.blue, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}
```

**Result is:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]